# outputting multiple lists in single Query (LINQ) C#

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i'm looking for a way to read the list one time to output 3 different lists.

For ex:

```
Class Item 
{ 
   public int key {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public bool CanTraid {get; set;}
}
```

Now if i have a `var myList = new list<Item>()` and let it have 30000 different item's

and `var deleted_Items = new list<Item>() {xItem_1,xItem_2, ..... }`

```
var j_1 =
      from i in myList 
      where i.key % 2 == 1
      select i ;

 var j_2 =
      from i in myList 
      where i.CanTraid == true
      select i ;

 var j_3 =
      from i in myList 
      join d in deleted_Items 
      where !(i.key == d.key)
      select i ;
```

So I have read 30K item's for 3 times and it's bad.

if i can read that list for one time and let it give me 3 different list it will be bater

something like

`j_ALL <list<Item>>` and let it be sorted like `j_ALL[0] <=> ( j_1 )`  `j_ALL[1] <=> ( j_2 )`  `j_ALL[2] <=> ( j_3 )`

Feel free to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have three sequence, each have the same type. Since you are talking of a `List<Item>`, I assume that you don't have to fetch the data from a database: they are already IEnumerable, not IQueryable.

```
IEnumerable<Item> J1 = ...
IEnumerable<Item> J2 - ...
IEnumerable<Item> J3 = ...
```

Because they are still IEnumerable, the List is not enumerated yet.

Let's add an identifier to each of the three sequences, and concatenate them

```
var itemsWithIdentifiers = J1.Select(item => new (Id = "J1", Value = item)              
                   .Concat(J2.Select(item => new (Id = "J2", Value = item)
                   .Concat(J3.Select(item => new (Id = "J3", Value = item);
```

Now convert them to a Loopkup table, using the identifier as Key, and Value as elements.
This is the one and only time that the sequence is enumerated:

```
ILookup<string, Item> lookupTable = itemsWithIdentifiers.ToLookup(
    item => item.Id,
    item => item.Value);
```

To access the result of your original j_1:

```
IEnumeable<Item> j_1Result = lookupTable["J1"];
```

This code can be slightly optimized if you use int as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate once, check each item and decide to which list it should be added:

```
var j_1 = new List<Item>();
var j_2 = new List<Item>();
var j_3 = new List<Item>();

foreach (var item in myList.Include(l => l.delete_items)
{
    if (item.key % 2 == 1) 
        j_1.Add(item);
    if (item.CanTraid)
        j_2.Add(item);
    if (item.key == item.delete_items.key)
        j_3.Add(item);
}
```

You can return the three lists like this:

```
return new List<List<Item>>{j_1, j_2, j_3};
```

Comment: thanks, i know how to do this but i wanted to expand my curiosity to make more use from the query for multiple things in one task.